# Leaflet: Toggle GeoJSON layers with Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, leaflet

I would like to be able to use checkboxes to toggle on/off layers on a map. The map will be loaded without any layers.

Right now my buttons look like this:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="points" value="addressPoints" /> ADDRESS POINTS</label>
```

I'm calling my GeoJSON layers like this:

```
L.geoJson(schoolDistricts, {
style: defaultStyle,
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("<h4>School District: " + feature.properties.name);
    layer.setStyle(defaultStyle);
(function(layer, properties) {
    layer.on("mouseover", function (e) {
        layer.setStyle(highlightStyle);
    });
    layer.on("mouseout", function (e) {
        layer.setStyle(defaultStyle);
    });
})(layer, feature.properties.name);
```

}
});

I know I need to add a change event to the checkbox code. I just don't really know how to go about writing a function to toggle the layer on and off. I have about 10 layers I will need to do this for so I'd like to be able to have a function that I can use for them all.

Hopefully this is enough information to go on.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this switcher](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html).

Comment: I was able to find an answer (http://rowanwinsemius.id.au/blog/add-and-remove-layers-with-leaflet-js/) that solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet has this capability built into the [layers control](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers) via an overlay object.  The layer control can accept an input for a basemap object and an overlay object.  The basemaps are toggled with radio buttons, the overlays are toggled with checkboxes.  Here's a simple example:

```
var basemapObj = {
"First Basemap": L.tileLayer(...),
"Second Basemap": L.tileLayer(...)
}

var overlayObj = {
"LayerA": L.geoJson(...),
"LayerB": L.geoJson(...)
}

L.control.layers(basemapObj, overlayObj).addTo(map);
```

The link listed in the comments above does the same thing as the built-in control, but requires that you write the code yourself and style the elements, etc.  Using the base Leaflet controls is much simpler.